# Conditional Feature based on Property

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In my bundle I have 2 features which both are about creating a folder structure based on the value of a property. As you can see my conditions are fairly simple. What is interesting is that only the condition on feature ONE works, while in feature TWO (where it does a comparison) it does nothing, but If I add the condition on every component I need just like in the other pasted code it works fine.

I was wondering why this is happening

```
<Property Id="NUMBER" />


   <Feature Id="ONE" Level="0">
      <Condition Level="1">
        <![CDATA[NOT NUMBER]]>
      </Condition>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="OneStructure"/>
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="TWO" Level="0">
      <Condition Level="1">
        <![CDATA[NUMBER <> ""]]>
      </Condition>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="OneStructure"/>
    </Feature>
```

-

```
                <Directory Id="dir77996843FCCE5E3734A5EDAA86FCE55B" Name="Input">
                    <Component Id="cmp2F4C23D858A887EF0B2539F7EC1884BE" Guid="{625D2714-157F-4B21-86C0-D4954A4E1F73}" KeyPath="yes">      <Condition>        <![CDATA[NUMBER <> ""]]> </Condition>
                        <CreateFolder />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue. Apparently it has to do with the condition only being evaluated once.

Instead of putting a condition directly in a feature, you can put conditions in a Control Event pertaining to a button in a given dialog.

Example:

```
  <Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Install">
    <!--Check property value here:-->
    <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="ALL">1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="ONE">NUMBER = 0</Publish>
    <Publish Event="Remove" Value="TWO">NUMBER = 1</Publish>
    <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" />
  </Control>
```

You would then change the value of the property "NUMBER" with a Radio Button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice alternative solution :D. Good to know!